# what the best way for escape html with rails 4: gsub('<', '&lt;') OR CGI.escapeHTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, html-escape-characters

I want escape html for data in controller, I found 2 ways:

```
text.gsub('<', '&lt;').gsub('>', '&gt;')
```

OR

```
CGI.escapeHTML(text)
```

What is the best, why?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way is, but I'll note that the first option is wrong in a lot of contexts. Big example being anything in a html attribute since it doesn't do any quotes.

Comment: It's not a problem if there is no html interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to just assign the data to instance variables and then output them in the view, which will handle encoding automatically:

controller:

```
def something
  @foo = "<test>"
end
```

something.html.erb

```
<%= @foo %>
```

Will output:

```
&lt;test&gt;
```

The view will do the right thing in most cases.

Comment: No, my context is the converse. User post `<a onclick="alert('test')">`, I want disable HTML and save it in bdd.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question... this does the same thing as the escapeHTML method (I'm pretty that's exactly the thing Rails calls automatically in this context). If a user put that and you output it this way, it would display the text instead of a link with runnable script.

Comment: I get markdown code from post parameter (by user), like on SO, but there is problem of security with XSS attack, so I want disable HTML sended by user, but not html created by converting markdown to html. This details as no importance, my question as clear I think.